# Adverbial form: 楽しみに or 楽しみで?

Tags: adverbs

I'm quite familiar with the different uses of the particles に and　で. However, right now I'm stuck, because I want to say the following in Japanese, and as I understand it, either one of these particles could provide the appropriate adverbial meaning if attached to the end of 楽しみ.

I would like to say in Japanese:

I will explain [i.e., make an explanation] it [to you] with pleasure.

Which one of the following is correct?

楽しみに説明します。　or   楽しみで説明します。

Comment: Shouldn't it be more like 喜んで?

Comment: @Chocolate, that should be an answer.

Comment: In your case, those are usually not considered particles. 楽しみな is a na-adjective (or 形容動詞), while 楽しみ itself works as a noun. We also have 楽しんで, which is a te-form (or 連用形 + 助動詞て) of the verb 楽しむ.

Answer (score 4):

For a Japanese equivalent to the phrase, "It is my pleasure to explain it to you," here are some suggestions:

> 喜んで教えます。
>
> 喜んで説明します。
>
> 喜んでお教えします。(with honorific)
>
> 喜んでご説明します。(with honorific)
>
> 喜んでご説明致します。 (more polite)
>
> 喜んでご説明させていただきます。(most polite)

楽しみに(する) is usually translated as "to look forward to something."

喜んで/よろこんで is an adverb meaning "  with pleasure ..." and is thus the more fitting choice for your question.

よろこんで is from the verb よろこぶ meaning "to rejoice/to take pleasure in."

Comment: maybe of interest regarding させていただきます:          
http://www.kobayashi.co.th/Kaicho-shitsu/zuihitu/keigo1.htm

Comment: Aside: This might be just my personal taste (excuse me if it is), but ご説明させていただきます sounds a little annoying to me, although it is not unheard.  I prefer 説明させていただきます when the use of させていただく is appropriate.  ご～させていただく sounds to me as if “I do not know which honorific expression is appropriate here, so I will put everything together!”

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the fact that I'm pretty sure that the correct word to use would be 喜んで（よろこんで） instead of 楽しみに, in some other similar sentence, you would use で, because "in this manner, I __"

In terms of the difference between 喜んで　and 楽しみに is that the former is not so much a matter of pleasure, as it is like saying "no problem" or something you would have no hesitation doing. In English we just say "with pleasure" as one of the things that we could say in that situation, but they don't all mean that you take pleasure in something. Tanoshii implies an actual, more solid pleasure. Something that feels good or is enjoyable. This is one of those things that can't just be directly translated.